# Parsing G-code with arduino from an sd card

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

As the title suggests, I am using the following function to read the parameters of some g-code files present on the SD card:

```
long parseParameters(String data, char* c){
    int offset = data.indexOf(c);
    int offset1 = data.lastIndexOf(" ", offset + 1);
    return offset1 > 0 ? data.substring(offset + 1, offset + offset1 + 1).toInt() : data.substring(offset + 1).toInt();
}

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    String q = "P3 S255"; // input
    Serial.println(parseParameters(p, "S")); // output
}

void loop(){

}
```

Only today, in an attempt to read the value of **S** in the string **P3 S255** has emerged in a small bug:

```
INPUT -> OUTPUT
P3 S255 -> 25 (wrong)
A20 P3 S255 -> 255 (Correct)
S255 -> 255 (Correct)
```

Why? Yet the code would seem correct to me..where did I go wrong?

Thanks in advance to everyone.. :)

Comment: This is a well-solved problem, and solved pretty rigorously before you.  Look up the Marlin or other firmware designed for the Arduino platform.  It's all open source and will either give you clues or convince you to quit reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I understand your point of view, but sometimes, while experimenting with programming languages, even being able to reinvent the wheel can give little satisfaction.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats the explanation:

```
int offset = data.indexOf(c); //in your example S

 "P3 S255";
     ^
  offset = 3
```

then you parse for offset1 but take another param namely " " after offset - but there is no " " in the string from offset+1 see above where the index is so it returns -1 why?

```
 myString.lastIndexOf(val, from) The index of val within the String, or -1 if not found. But we find something:

offset = 3;
offset1 = 2 ==> offset1 > 0 ==> data.substring(offset + 1, offset + offset1 + 1).toInt()
```

which leads to

```
 data.substring(3 + 1, 3 + 2 + 1).toInt()
      "P3 S*4*25*6*5"; which results to 25 as you already know
```

> to (optional): the index to end the substring **before**.

So you have correct for the S in the begin by changing to

```
data.substring(offset + 1, offset + 1 + offset1 + 1).toInt()
```

Explanation: You start at offset + 1 this has to be equal in from and to (= same starting point for your calculation)

Comment: Wow! what a detailed explanation! Thanks.. :)